# mongodb alphabetical sort rolling-over

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Good Day.

I have a name, that I want to see where it would fall in alphabetical order in the database. My search works fine except if it would become the first entry...then I get the last entry. So, if `aarden` is the input, the result return is `zimmer`. I'd like to throw an error or some message rather than the rolled-over value `zimmer`.

Here's the query:
`db.getCollection('person').find({nameLast: {$lt: "aarden"}, nameFirst: {$lt: "joe"}})
  .sort({"nameLast": -1, "nameFirst": 1}).limit(1)`

Suggestions?
I figure I can either see if the name returned is not the same leading character "A" in this case, but then if the search term is "Bath" and the returned name is "Apple", seems complex (unless I search with some regex?), or have I missed a mongo sort parameter?

Edit: better example.

Here's the database when sorted alphabetically:

`Abbott, Fred
Abreu, Juan
Adam, Jason
...
Zimmerman, Raul`

If my search name is `Acrue, William` the query would (and does) return the document `Abreu, Juan`, because this name (`Abreu`) would come *before* the name (`Acrue, William`).

If my search name is `Aaron, Hank` it would fall *before* `Abbott, Fred`. The query actually returns the last value (when sorted) `Zimmer, Raul`. So, it 'rolls-over.'

I'd rather have a error message saying something like `ERROR: no entry before {searchTerm}`

Comment: It is very confusing of what is your requirement, what is desired output of your logic and what is actual output of your logic.

Comment: is it a capitalization issue? because `"Aarden" < "Zimmer" < "aarden"`

Comment: No, it's not a capitalization issue. (doubled checked just now, as the names in the db are capitalized, and I get the same issue whether `aarden` or 'Aarden'. I actually didn't copy over my query correctly to SO, as it is capitalized in my code.